# Improving the efficiency of pre-caching files on a server

Tags: bash, curl, performance-testing

I'm an intern testing a transparent caching solution that we've plunked down on a server in our lab. To do so, I'm pre-caching some files for a test involving new and already-cached content.

However, we have 48 GB of RAM on that machine, and we're using small (16 KB) files for the test, so to keep us actually going back to our TC solution, I'm caching about six million of these files. Yikes.

I've been running the following bash script in the hope of spinning off a bunch of parallel processes so that this pre-caching takes a manageable amount of time, (ignore the dummy IP):

`for ((i=0;i<1000;i++)); do for ((j=$((6000*i));j<$((6000*$((i+1))));j++)); do curl x.x.x.x/originDir/test16k_${j}.txt > /dev/null 2>&1 & done; wait; done;`

However, I'm still only getting about 1000 files cached every few seconds over our 10 Gbps fiber-optic, which was about what I got when I was doing sequential `curls`. For six million files, that's going to be a lot of seconds.

Does anyone know a better way to go about this?

Many thanks,
RS

Comment: You can run all the jobs concurrently but do you think your machine can execute them all in parallel? Check on top what your cpu utilization looks like to determine if your problem is a lack of cpu. If it is, your best bet might to be use temporary machines on an Amazon cluster or something along those lines.

Comment: Even with only 5 Gbps of usable bandwidth, you could pull down nearly 41,000 of your test files each second. I think your bottleneck may be how fast you can launch the `curl`s, not how many you can run in parallel.

Comment: chpener, is that an issue that more parallel processes each launching curls would solve, or is there a limit on how many curls can be up (or going up) at once?

EDIT: Also, my lab has nice, beefy Dell Poweredge servers retrofitted with SSDs and extra RAM and such. I'd be very surprised if the process was hardware-gated.

Comment: you might want to look at other tags that are available here on S.O. I recall there are things like performance, performance-testing, testing, maybe a few others. Be sure to check the # of followers, to get the most 'eyes' on your problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One change would be to make use of curl's step counter so that curl does the iterations instead of bash.  This should speed it up because you will be avoiding bash interpreter and process start times.

```
curl x.x.x.x/originDir/test16k_[0-5999].txt
```

Comment: A variant on this worked! I had to keep the outer loop so as to get to all of the files I needed to, but it's blazing along now.

Here was my final, working code:
`for ((i=0;i<599;i++)); do curl x.x.x.x/originDir/test16k_${i}[0-99999].txt > /dev/null 2>&1 & done;`